# Installing Docker Desktop in windows server 2022-

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-desktop, windows-server-2022

I am trying to install Docker in windows server 2022 in AWS. when i install docker desktop and when i start it says DockerEngine Stopped. also i installed WSL2 also i get error

By using WSL2 when i try to install ubuntu package i got this error. where WSL in version 2

> wsl.exe --install Ubuntu-22.04
> Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is already installed.
> Launching Ubuntu 22.04 LTS...
> Installing, this may take a few minutes...
> WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102
> Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
> For information please visit https://aka.ms/enablevirtualization

Comment: Maybe you just need to enable virtualisation in Windows?